# Dropdowns - selects dynamics-jquery

Tags: html-select

I'm try to do a dynamic selects with jQuery, example:

```
<select >
<option value=1> 1</option>
<option value=2> 2</option>
<option value=3> 3</option>
<option value=4> 4</option>
</select>
```

when I get value="x"

I would like to add

```
count=x;
for(int i=1 ; i<=count; i++){
<select > </select>
}
```

I have a problem with me code , this code add and add.. I dont want this
I just want add the 'x' select

http://jsfiddle.net/hqLPp/48/

Comment: May I know what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: sorry for my english, I try to.I want to do is the following:

I have a dropdown in which I have options "1,2,3 ... x", when you choose one of these numbers, I would like to add "<select>" depending on the number that I chose, I have a problem with my code, only thing it does is add.

Comment: Its ok I can understand, if you tell the requirement much more clearly it is easy to solve the problem

Comment: I want to add a number of "selects" depending on another select chosen above. I hope you can understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want result on same page, then this might be useful,

this will be on your page, where you want result

```
    <script>
    function showSelectBox(str)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true); // Pass value to another page Here->test
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>


    <select name='check' onchange="showSelectBox(this.value)">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <div id="myresult">


    </div>
```

Now On test.php Simply Call Value & put select box,

```
    <?php
    $q = $_GET['q'];

    for($i=1 ; $i<=$q; $i++)
    {
        echo '<select > </select>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is not working. I speak spanish because I dont understand somethings. Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: tengo una caja que tiene numeros, del 1 al 4 , o los que yo quiera, al momento de escoger digamos 3, que me salgan 3 cajas, si escojo 2, que me salgan 2 y asi sucesivamente, pero todo que cargue en la misma pagina. I hope you can understand me, thanks